# Survival of the Fittest

Tags: smash-up

Please clarify I am playing Survival of the Fittest properly.

Two of the bases in play both have two creatures on them, one is strength 3 and one is strength 2. I play Survival of the Fittest and both strength 2 creatures are destroyed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct.

The card text :

> Destroy the lowest-power minion(you choose in case of a tie) on each
>   base with higher-power minion.

So the Lowest minion (even yours) on each base with a higher minion (from anyone) die.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a minion in your hand with a higher power than a minion on a particular base, you may destroy the lower power minion on that base and replace it with the one from your hand with a higher power. Repeat for each base until you have no more minions in your hand.

Comment: Do you have any rules or references to back this up?

Comment: This is flat out wrong. The card doesn't say anything about replacing, and Smash Up is not the kind of game where you get to interpret things that aren't written on the card.

Comment: it says destroy the lowest power minion with higher-power minion, it is ambiguous about if the higher power is already on the base of it the player gets to place the higher power minion